# Use wp_list_categories to list parent categories from actual term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization, taxonomy, terms

I currently have a taxonomy called wpsc_product_category. Under that taxonomy I have several terms used as sub-categories, and finally each sub-category has a number of products. I'm trying to use wp_list_categories to show an ul starting from the parent category of the current product your are viewing. ¿Is this possible?

```
<?php    

$taxonomy     = 'wpsc_product_category';
$orderby      = 'name'; 
$show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$title        = '';
$child_of     = $actualcategoryparentid

$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
  'orderby'      => $orderby,
  'show_count'   => $show_count,
  'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
  'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
  'title_li'     => $title
  'child_of'     => $child_of
);
?>

<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

I thought of something like this, but I don't know how to retrieve $actualcategoryparentid.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work:

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'wpsc_product_category' );
foreach($terms as $term){
    if($term->parent != 0){
        // this category has a parent and its id is $term->parent
    }
}
```

Comment: So I just have to add that and then replace $terms for $actualcategoryparentid?

Comment: $term->parent within the foreach loop is what would be $actualcategoryparentid, but consider that if a product has more than one category with a parent, there will be more than one $term->parent

Comment: Oh i got it! I have to do $child_of = $term->parent;

Comment: Hmm I see. I hope I don't run into that problem too soon. Thanks for the helo Milo :)

Comment: Milo, would it be possible to get the name of $term->parent too? So I can echo it before listing the products?

Comment: you'd have to use `get_term( $term->parent, 'wpsc_product_category' )` to fetch the name of the parent. see [get term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term).

Comment: Something like <?php $name = get_term( $term->parent, 'wpsc_product_category' , ARRAY_A); ?> I don't know where the $name = $term->name; part takes place. Thanks for your time!

Comment: `$parentterm = get_term( $term->parent, 'wpsc_product_category' ); echo $parentterm->name;`